# Steam no longer launching after recent Ubuntu update

Tags: nvidia, steam

After a recent update to Ubuntu to 18.04.4, Steam is no longer launching for me. I realize that this has been posted at various times, but I tried many of the solutions suggested in those threads to no avail. Below is steam's console output:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
/home/daveboat/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
[2020-04-02 23:38:36] Startup - updater built Mar 26 2020 22:45:57
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  51
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  52
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2020-04-02 23:38:36] Checking for update on startup
[2020-04-02 23:38:36] Checking for available updates...
[2020-04-02 23:38:36] Downloading manifest: client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2020-04-02 23:38:36] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1585264767, installed version 1585264767
[2020-04-02 23:38:36] Nothing to do
[2020-04-02 23:38:36] Verifying installation...
[2020-04-02 23:38:36] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2020-04-02 23:38:37] Verification complete
```

I am running a Dell XPS 15 with a GTX 1650, with nvidia-drivers-440 installed.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone finds this in the future, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/fu1228/steam_no_longer_launching_after_recent_ubuntu/fme6jnq/)'s the solution that worked for me, from a user on Reddit. It seems using nVidia's own installers works better than using apt. The detailed steps:

1. Download the nVidia drivers from [nVidia's website](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/157462/en-us). For me, this was version 440.64.
2. Log out
3. Enter the console with Ctrl-Alt-F2
4. Stop gdm with `sudo systemctl stop gdm` -- afterwards, I had to Ctrl-Alt-F2 again to get back to the console.
5. Remove previous drivers installed by apt with `sudo apt remove '^nvidia.*'`
6. Install the downloaded drivers with `sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.64.run`
7. Restart gdm with `sudo systemctl start gdm`

Steam was able to start after these steps for me.

Comment: Please add some more information on how the content of the link solved your problem. The link may not be available in the future.